# Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Businesses' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF

Tags: sql, asp.net

i created an empty migration and added this code to it :

public override void Up()
        {

```
        Sql("INSERT INTO Businesses (Id, Field) VALUES (1, 'Restaurant')");
        Sql("INSERT INTO Businesses (Id, Field) VALUES (2, 'FastFood')");
        Sql("INSERT INTO Businesses (Id, Field) VALUES (3, 'Breakfast')");
        Sql("INSERT INTO Businesses (Id, Field) VALUES (4, 'Bar')");

    }

    public override void Down()
    {

        Sql("DELETE FROM Businesses WHERE Id IN (1, 2, 3, 4)");

    }
```

to populate the field table . but when i want to update the database i get this error :

Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Businesses' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

what have i done wrong ?

Comment: Set IDENTITY_INSERT to ON or do not insert IDs...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your database is setup to insert and auto increment your Id column. Simply omit the column from your SQL queries.

```
INSERT INTO Businesses (Field) VALUES ('Restaurant')
INSERT INTO Businesses (Field) VALUES ('FastFood')
INSERT INTO Businesses (Field) VALUES ('Breakfast')
INSERT INTO Businesses (Field) VALUES ('Bar')
```

I see later on you intend to delete the inserted rows. You will likely want to do something more sophisticated with your where statement, because the Id field is not guaranteed to be 1, 2, 3, and 4.